# SQL Server Firewall Rules UI seems broken on Azure Portal

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database

We are not able to manage `SQL Server Firewall Rules` within **Azure Portal UI** as of today.

The page **(Azure Portal > SQL Servers > Firewalls and virtual networks)** overall seems broken (with error messages popping on **Chrome DevTools**). It is not correctly displaying the `Current Firewall Rules` and allowing the creation of new rules - the "Add client IP" button does nothing.

We noticed that the UI for this page has changed. For e.g., displaying of a new field called `Connection Policy`.

I don't know if they are related, nevertheless it is a coincidence.

Is anyone else experiencing this?

Example of an error displayed in **DevTools**:

```
fKKDU9g2sNts.js:9 [SqlAzureExtension]  10:05:58 AM MsPortalFx.Base.Diagnostics.ErrorReporter 3 MsPortalFx.Base.Diagnostics.ErrorReporter: message: Cannot read property 'create' of null
stack: TypeError: Cannot read property 'create' of null
    at c.execute (https://afd.hosting.portal.azure.net/sqlazureextension/Content/Dynamic/e0Cos2cQndP9.js:2:1366)
    at n.invoke (https://portal.azure.com/Content/Dynamic/fKKDU9g2sNts.js:35:20403)
    at Array.<anonymous> (https://portal.azure.com/Content/Dynamic/fKKDU9g2sNts.js:37:20414)
    at n.handleMessage (https://portal.azure.com/Content/Dynamic/fKKDU9g2sNts.js:37:4483)
    at n.handleEventMessage (https://portal.azure.com/Content/Dynamic/fKKDU9g2sNts.js:37:20717)
    at Array.<anonymous> (https://portal.azure.com/Content/Dynamic/fKKDU9g2sNts.js:37:22835)
    at n.handleMessage (https://portal.azure.com/Content/Dynamic/fKKDU9g2sNts.js:37:4483)
    at _handleMessage (https://portal.azure.com/Content/Dynamic/fKKDU9g2sNts.js:37:9991)
    at p (https://portal.azure.com/Content/Dynamic/fKKDU9g2sNts.js:37:817)
    at n._handler (https://portal.azure.com/Content/Dynamic/fKKDU9g2sNts.js:37:10239)
From RPC: fx -> SqlAzureExtension
(Callstack capturing is not enabled. Use ?trace=diagnostics to enable it.)
```

Comment: This happens occasionally as new functionality is rolled out. I've occasionally had luck with clearing all cached files for portal.azure.com, and deleting all cookies for the site as well.

Answer (score 2):

Do you have an Azure Support Plan? If you do, this should go to support. If you do not have a support plan, can you send an email with your Azure Subscription GUID to AzCommunity (azcommunity@microsoft.com) and they should provide you further instructions.

Meanwhile you can use Transact-SQL to manage firewall rules.

```
-- Create server-level firewall setting for only IP 0.0.0.2  
exec sp_set_firewall_rule N'Example setting 1', '0.0.0.2', '0.0.0.2';  

-- Update server-level firewall setting to create a range of allowed IP addresses
exec sp_set_firewall_rule N'Example setting 1', '0.0.0.2', '0.0.0.4';
```

To list firewall rules at the database level you just need to query the sys.database_firewall_rules view. To list firewall rules at the server level, you just need to query the sys.firewall_rules view.

Comment: Hello @alberto-morillo. Thanks for the response. For now I am able to manage rules using Powershell commands on the Cloud Shell. Strangely enough, I tried creating a SQL Server resource from scratch, and from there I am able to set Firewall Rules without issues. So maybe this issue happens because of some particularity of a SQL Server resource that was already created prior to this "new UI".

Comment: Email sent on instructions to enable one-time support request. In return, can you please update this post with the resolution or the root cause, as it is helpful to others who might be experiencing the same behavior.

Comment: Any resolution to this by now? I have the same problem. Adding the client IP pretends the rule gets added, but the console shows errors and the rule doesn't actually get created.